# Jquery append option to select and get the selected value

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Having trouble with this part.
I have a select populated with asp.net mvc and 2 other empty select that is populated by jquery

```
<select id="Type" onchange="GetClassification(this.value);">
    @foreach (var item in Type)
    {
      <option value="@item.TypeID">@item.TypeName</option>
    }
</select>

<select id="Classification" onchange="GetDescription(this.value);">
</select>

<select id="Description" onchange="GetDescriptionTips(this.value);">
</select>
```

So based on first select it populates the sencond, based on second it populates the third. First one populates right, second one populates right, third one doesn't populate on document ready.

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
      $(function () {
         var type = $("#Type option:selected").val();
         GetClassification(type);
      });
    });

    function GetClassification(typeID) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/types/Classification',
            data: { typeID: typeID },
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                $('#Classification option').remove();
                $.each(data, function (index, val) {
                    var optionTag = $('<option></option>');
                    $(optionTag).val(val.ClassificationID).text(val.ClassificationName);
                    $('#Classification').append(optionTag);
                });
            }
        });
    var classification = $("#Classification option:selected").val();
    GetDescription(classification);
}

function GetDescription(classificationID) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/types/Description',
        data: { classificationID: classificationID },
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            $('#Description option').remove();
            $.each(data, function (index, val) {
                var optionTag = $('<option></option>');
                $(optionTag).val(val.DescriptionID).text(val.DescriptionName);
                $('#Description').append(optionTag);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

After load page, if I select second one it changes the third one right, but if change the first, it only changes the second.
What I need is on load populate the second and third, then on change the first, re populate the second and third, and on change the second re-populate the third.

I can see it doesn't assign selected on any stage, so I am not sure if need assign it.

Hope I explained good.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Move `var classification = $("#Classification option:selected").val(); GetDescription(classification);` into the success callback after the `$.each` statement (Ajax calls are async so `GetDescription` is running before `GetClassification` is completed.

Comment: Well it might now load the options, but whats the point. It wont post back anything so not sure what your doing with this. And you really should learn to use the strongly type html helpers in MVC.

Comment: I am not using this anywhere. It was just a test I was trying to do. Thanks again.

Comment: OK, not a problem then, but I think you are making unnecessary ajax calls using this technique. Why populate the subsequent dropdowns in document ready (what are the chances that the user will accept the first option in all of them - you are just going to have to make additional calls anyway)?

Answer (score 0):

First of all try to follow this [Don't repeat yourself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), here is simple algo:

```
1.Choose all selects
2.Create only one ajax function and pass params like url, data, etc to it
3.In success function proccess your response from the server
4.find all next selects and clean them up or remove options as u wish
```

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery, try using the `.on('chang', function(){...)` event handler. Because you are changing the DOM and the `on()` method can detect the change event even the DOM changed after document ready.